# cost of gaussian elimination in numerical

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, numerical-methods

In the following question I have solved the system

$$2x_1-x_2=2$$
$$-x_1+3x_2 = 4$$

Using gaussian elimination. Below are the workings, however I am wonder what is the cost of this process? how do I count the amount of operations?

$$ A= 
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
2&-1\\-1&3
\end{matrix}
\bigg] = 
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
2\\4 
\end{matrix}
\bigg]
$$

for row $2$ multiplying Row $1$ by 2 and adding to row $2$ gives

$$ A= 
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
2&-1\\0&5
\end{matrix}
\bigg] = 
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
2\\10 
\end{matrix}
\bigg]
$$

using back sub we get $x_2=2$ and $x_1=\frac{2+1\times 2}{2} = 2$

But what was the cost of this?

Comment: https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/classes/gateway_2014/lecture_week03.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider a system of $m$ equations with $m$ unknowns then we have the system:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12} &\dots& a_{1m} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} &\dots & a_{2m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \dots & a_{mm}
 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\x_m \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_m \end{pmatrix}$$

Through Gaussian Elimination we transform the system into: 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
u_{11} & u_{12} &\dots& u_{1m} \\
 & u_{22} &\dots & u_{2m} \\
 & & \ddots & \vdots \\
 &  &  & u_{mm}
 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\x_m \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} g_1 \\ g_2 \\ \vdots \\ g_m \end{pmatrix}$$
if we carefully count the number of operations in transforming $A$ into $U$ we can get the following:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\textrm{step} & \textrm{addition} & \textrm{multiplication} & \textrm{division} \\
\hline
1 & (m-1)^2 & (m-1)^2 & m-1 \\
2 & (m-2)^2 & (m-2)^2 & m-2 \\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \vdots \\
m -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \\
\hline
\textrm{total}: & 6^{-1}m(m-1)(2m-1) &  6^{-1}m(m-1)(2m-1) & 2^{-1}n(n-1)
\end{array}

similarly to transform $b$ into $g$ we have $2^{-1}m(m-1)$ additions and multiplications

finally, when back-solving we have $2^{-1}m(m-1)$ additions and $2^{-1}m(m+1)$ multiplications

so the total number of operations required is: $$\frac{m(m(4m+9)-7)}{6}$$

i.e. for a $2\times 2$ system we see that we require 9 operations

Comment: Why assume that the matrix is a square?!

Comment: the original question asked about a square matrix.  one could of course generalize this to non-square matrices.

Comment: The original question asked about 2x2. Why did you talk about mxm but not mxn?

Comment: @NikeDattani: because 2=2?

Comment: But $ m\ne 2  $.